# Inspecting javascript variables as code popups in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

Anyone know how you get the yellow popup to appear when inspecting javascript variables in chrome? Apparently you just hover over the variable when the debugger is paused to see a variables current state but for whatever reason I can't get this to work.

If you have no idea what I'm talking about checkout this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the variable you are hovering over is in the context of the current breakpoint?

Comment: Would you mind linking to the video from which you took this screenshot?

Comment: The screenshot is from a video over at codeschool http://www.codeschool.com/ the course is http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/ video is http://www.viddler.com/file/d/53aad68b.mp4 The variable is in the current context of the breakpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why this wasn't working but I tired a clean install of chrome on a different user profile on my mac and worked fine. So I went back and dumped all the preferences and application support files and turned off all extension on my profile and it worked!!! So moral of the story do a clean install of Chrome.

Comment: This did not work for me as of Version 79.0.3945.79 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me before. Just close all Chrome instances or restart it. This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me on 16/12/19, with version 79. But in Chrome canary, it is working fine. People who need can download it [here](https://www.google.com/chrome/canary/) (you can use it for now) or you can use Chrome Dev [here](https://www.google.com/chrome/dev/)

For the people who don't know about Chrome Canary or Dev

Chrome Canary is an experimental version of the popular Chrome browser. Google offers four release channels for its Chrome browser: Stable, Beta, Dev, and Canary. Most people use the Stable release of Chrome, which is rigorously tested and considered very reliable.

By contrast, Chrome Canary may appeal to people who like noodling around with new technology and want to get an advance look at what the standard Chrome browser may look like in the future.