# Variable Values Not Popping Up on Mouse Over in Chrome Debugger

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Until recently, when paused in Chrome debugger on a breakpoint, the current state of a JavaScript variable, array or object would pop up in a yellow dialog if hovered over with a mouse. That is no longer working though I'm at a loss to know what has changed. Has anyone else experienced this? It's really making debugging a lot more difficult on this computer. My other computer still has the normal behavior in Chrome Dev Tools (both Windows 7 machines). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I seem to have this issue too - using Chrome version 30.0.1599.101 m. I can however see tooltips with the full values by hovering over the values in the Scope/Local/Global Variables pane.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721187/inspecting-javascript-variables-as-code-popups-in-chrome

Comment: Thank you, Steve. This appears to be resolved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved in a later version of Chrome and is no longer an issue.

Comment: Yes, working better for me too (version 39.0.2171.71 m). But have to select the variable first, e.g. by double clicking on it before hovering - would ideally prefer not to have to do this.

Comment: Happening to me as of 12/13/2019 with `Version 79.0.3945.79 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1033891

Comment: For me too in 15/12/2019

Comment: It was also happening to me. Hopefully it will be fixed very soon.

Comment: Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit) for me too

Comment: 8 Years later and it's still occurring from time to time.

Comment: Still occurring for me.

Comment: Still occurring for me.

Comment: Happening to me as of mid-September 2022

Comment: for me too, any solution?

Comment: I started getting it a few months ago

Comment: Me too not working for me version "106.0.5249.103"

Comment: Seems to still happen - Dec 22

Answer (score 24):

The same thing happened to me on 16/12/19, with version 79. But in Chrome canary, it is working fine. People who need can download it [here](https://www.google.com/chrome/canary/)  (you can use it for now) or you can use Chrome Dev [here](https://www.google.com/chrome/dev/)

For the people who don't know about Chrome Canary or Dev

Chrome Canary is an experimental version of the popular Chrome browser. Google offers four release channels for its Chrome browser: Stable, Beta, Dev, and Canary. Most people use the Stable release of Chrome, which is rigorously tested and considered very reliable.

By contrast, Chrome Canary may appeal to people who like noodling around with new technology and want to get an advance look at what the standard Chrome browser may look like in the future.

Comment: For your reference **https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1033891**

Comment: I was facing the same issue since 16-12-2019 but after reaching out this post I installed canary now I am able to see debug tooltip.

Comment: It's working only partially in Canary.
Hovering over variables in a parent function doesn't work sometimes (and it used to work even outside the current scope). Also selecting hex numbers: "1e3" anywhere in the code used to work, now it doesn't.

Comment: The mentioned issue (in Canary) seems to be intentional: https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/%2B/1835357
But still there are some cases where it is useful to be able to select outside the innermost scope.

Comment: Still facing this issue on 107.0.5280.0 (Official Build) canary (arm64).

Answer (score 1):

Updated my chrome to **version 79.0.3945.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)**. popup after hovering to variable is not showing.
Luckily, I found solution on google(don't know about the source now). Simply ***turn off the 
Hardware acceleration feature*** and it worked. If you ignore impact of hardware acceleration turn off, this is the ideal one.

Canary version 81>= is another solution for this feature to work.